# How to fix gamepad problem with DOSBox-ed One Must Fall 2097?

Tags: controllers, dosbox, one-must-fall-2097

Recently I played an excellent, 1994 now-freeware fighting game, One Must Fall 2097. The game works wonderfully under DOSBox, with fully supported sound and gamepad control, which I personally prefer and used till now.

I completed the arcade mode and decided to try the tournament mode, which I remember was pretty awesome. Unfortunately, when I enter the character creation screen, the cursor (controlled by gamepad) seems to go mad, behaves as it would be completely uncalibrated and keeps pushing down-right direction, thus making it impossible to navigate through tournament mode menus. The problem does not occur when I choose to use keyboard controls.

Are there any known issues connected with DOSBox support for gamepads? Are any walkarounds available?

If it's purely a game-related problem, is there any patch or fix for OMF2097 gamepad support?

I use a relatively old, game-port based gamepad, which never caused me any trouble.

Comment: Your reminder of how awesome OMF 2097 is may inspire me to try this and let you know what I find.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem with Mega Man X in DOSBox under Ubuntu 10.04. I disabled joystick support in dosbox config and mapped some keyboard keys on Logitec F710 using qjoypad.

Comment: Could you recommend any specific joypad mapping application for Windows platforms? I am not using linux so it seems qjoypad is not an option. I tried to use Xpadder but I don't like it.

Comment: On Windows I tried only Xpadder, and I like it, it fits perfectly for my needs. Though, I can confirm, that it is not very convenient to switch between profiles for a certain game. For example, I have one profile for Dark Void Zero, and another - for Braid.